# How to get button press event from camera

Tags: java, usb4java

I've got a dental camera and iam try to get windows to press space when the camera button is pressed

I have the OEM software and driver installed, it works perfect, gets the feed and makes a snapshot when camera button is pressed. I need to use another software for the feed and the snapshot, the software gets the feed but doesn't react to camera button, it only reacts to space key press(part of the oem driver), so my way of solving this was getting the device by product id and listening the button press event and remapping it space press.
I am pretty much stuck at this point.
How can I listen on events coming from the device I've got?

```
   public static Device findDCam(){
        // Create the libusb context
        Context context = new Context();

        // Initialize the libusb context
        int result = LibUsb.init(context);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb", result);
        }

        // Read the USB device list
        DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
        result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
        }

        try
        {
            // Iterate over all devices and list them
            for (Device device: list)
            {

                DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
                result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);
                if (result < 0)
                {
                    throw new LibUsbException(
                            "Unable to read device descriptor", result);
                }

                if(descriptor.idProduct()== -3810){
                    System.out.println("D cam found");
                    return device;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure the allocated device list is freed
            LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);
        }

        // Deinitialize the libusb context
        LibUsb.exit(context);
        return null;

    }
```

I've also thought that maybe it's impossible using usb4java since as far as i understood, if i want to listen on the usb port i need to take control from the driver and then its pointless.
Maybe iam going all wrong and i should use the driver instead?
Or maybe there is an app that can read button presses from a specific device and remap it?

Answer (score 0):

If the camera has a standard driver, this should work through this [video capture SDK](https://www.datastead.com/products/video-sdk/). To quick test it, run the demo executable included in the package, select the camera in the list, check the "webcam snapshot button" checkbox and start the camera. Then press the camera button to test the snapshot.